# How to set axis line at bottom when all data 0 in jfreechart's bar chart?

Tags: jfreechart

I use Jfreechart's bar chart to show data. But in case all data is 0, the axis line will be displayed in middle of chart. I just want to display the axis line in bottom as usual cases.
How can I configure it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a [`DefaultCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html) for example, use the [`clear()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html#clear%28%29) method when all values are sufficiently close to zero that you want to display no data. Alternatively, use [`setRangeWithMargins()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setRangeWithMargins%28double,%20double%29) when a specific range would be more meaningful.